# Designer fields for Julia type

Tags: julia

I want a type which takes an argument and uses that argument to construct a list internal to the type, something like this:

```
type Foo
    index::Int
    end

type Goo
    size::Int
    myList = [Foo(i) for i in 1:size]

    Goo(size) = new(size)
    end
```

I've tried it a number of different ways, the way shown here hopefully communicates what I'm trying to do.  I don't really care about `Goo` retaining the size information, all I want is for it to use that information to construct a list of `Foo` objects of length `size` internal to an instance of type `Goo`.

On an unrelated note, I read the github discussion and the discussion on google groups concerning allowing abstract field types, I really wish that feature was included in Julia, the work arounds given make the code unnecessarily convoluted and confusing (in my opinion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work. Here is the version with an outer constructor:

```
type Foo
    index::Int
end

type Goo
    mylist::Vector{Foo}
end
Goo(size::Int) = Goo([Foo(i) for i in 1:size])
```

or with an inner constructor

```
type Goo
    mylist::Vector{Foo}
    Goo(size::Int) = new([Foo(i) for i in 1:size])
end
```

As for the abstract type "issue", I don't think the issue is over completely - interfaces may be the solution. Regardless, many packages are working just fine without abstract type fields.

Comment: Yes this works, however is there no way to make this an inner constructor method?  Why are the inputs of `Goo` and `new` required to be the same for inner constructor methods?

Comment: Just added inner constructor - they aren't, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: oh nice, not sure what I was doing wrong before, thanks.